# how to bring a core_config_data to its last state?

Tags: magento2.3, core-config-data

I have done an update which I should not have and backup functionality on magento was not enabled, how can I rollback that last command?
is there a chance somewhere I can get the data back?
since I did not flush the cache, site is stable at the moment

please help me.

Comment: Contact your host, maybe they have a backup

Comment: @PЯINCƏ is correct, you should send email to the server support team and you need to ask DB backup before a week or month. Once they provide DB, you need to set up this in your local and get core_config_data.

Comment: yea so I ended up asking host providers and they gave me whole db and I extracted the core table